# Interface Builder storyboarding

Tags: xcode

I want to create an application using storyboarding in xcode 4 but when i create new poject there is no any option to create like "using storyboard" which is available in xcode 4.2.

please guide me..

Comment: you can refer [this tutorial](http://kurrytran.blogspot.com/2011/07/simple-ios-5-tutorial-using-storyboard.html) . Hope this will help you in learning storyboard in xcode 4.xxx

Answer (score 1):

New|Project
Select Single View Application[image: Single View Application]
Press Next
In the options dialog, select the "Use Storyboard" check box. It's beneath the device family dropdown.[image: Options Dialog]

Answer (score 1):

Hi a step by step for those who (like me) don't like searching for hours on end for which box to tick ^^

http://kurrytran.blogspot.co.uk/2011/07/simple-ios-5-tutorial-using-storyboard.html